# IFS usage in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I have

```
$ IFS=123

$ myvar=abc1def1ghi

$ for i in "$myvar";  do echo i $i;  done
i abc def ghi

$ for i in $myvar;  do echo i $i;  done
i abc
i def
i ghi

$ myvar="abc1def1ghi"

$ for i in "$myvar";  do echo i $i;  done
i abc def ghi

$ for i in $myvar;  do echo i $i;  done
i abc
i def
i ghi
```

I think I understand whats happening in 2nd and 4th for loops. But I do not understand why 1 was not printed in 1st and 3rd for loops. The whole idea of IFS is confusing to me in general.

Comment: The number `1` is not printed because you did not quote `$i`. Instead, if you write `echo i "$i"` the result will be the expected `abc1def1ghi`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you say $var_name then 1 is interpreted as a separator and hence you see the string as cut into pieces.

```
$ IFS=123

$ myvar=abc1def1ghi

$ echo $myvar
abc def ghi
```

When you add quotes around the variable, you demand for the absolute value of the variable without any processing.

```
$ echo "$myvar"
abc1def1ghi
```

Now coming to your question **about 1st loop**,

```
$ for i in "$myvar";  do echo i $i;  done
```

is equivalent to

```
$ for i in "abc1def1gh1";  do echo i $i;  done
```

'i' gets assigned "abc1def1gh1" and it prints out the value of variable 'i'. This time '1' is interpreted as a separator while printing 'i'. This is what happened while running the loop:

```
$ i="abc1def1gh1"

$ echo $i
abc def gh
```

Same thing happens in the 3rd loop.

Now **if you want '1' to be printed, then** add quotes around $i in the loop.
ie. change this:

```
$ for i in "abc1def1gh1";  do echo i $i;  done
i abc def gh
```

to

```
$ for i in "abc1def1gh1";  do echo i "$i";  done
i abc1def1gh1
```

Comment: Why were spaces printed instead of 1 when you print the variable keeping in double quotes?

Comment: Not getting your concern. Can you provide example ?

Comment: @abc: you had `$myvar` in double-quotes in the `for` command, so IFS didn't affect it.  But `$i` was *not* in double-quotes, so it got split based on IFS and passed to `echo` as three separate arguments: "abc", "def", and "gh".  `echo` prints its arguments with spaces between them, so the net result is that the "1"s got turned into spaces.

Answer (score 2):

`IFS` or internal field separator is a sequence of characters where each character acts as a delimiter to split a result into multiple pieces.To understand the differences of the output, we need to see when the `IFS` has been applied on the string. Let's see first one:

```
$ IFS=123
$ myvar=abc1def1ghi
$ for i in "$myvar";  do echo i $i;  done
i abc def ghi
```

If we put values of each variables, the piece of code will be looked like this:

```
$ IFS=123
$ myvar=abc1def1ghi
$ for i in "abc1def1ghi";  do echo i abc1def1ghi;  done
```

`IFS` is applied only at `echo i abc1def1ghi`. So the output will be `i abc def ghi`. 
Now let's see the second one:

```
$ IFS=123
$ myvar=abc1def1ghi
$ for i in $myvar;  do echo i $i;  done
```

For the above code, the `IFS` will be applied at the building of the `for loop` when the `myvar` value is put and the code will look like this:

```
$ IFS=123
$ myvar=abc1def1ghi
$ for i in abc def ghi;  do echo i $i;  done
```

So the `for loop` will iterate three times and the output will be:

```
   i abc
   i def
   i ghi
```

So the final conclusion is that due to the double-quotes on the `$myvar` , `IFS` has not been applied on that.